# IE loses all windowHandles after simply calling navigate() in WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've seen a lot of related questions out there, but nothing with an answer that will fix my problem. I start IEServerDriver, my browser loads up at the default WebDriver page. Then I have a simple call like

```
WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(urlthatredirectstohttps);
```

Bang, suddenly on some browsers, on some tests machines I've lost all windowhandles, my WebDriver has become unusable. Either I get a Window is Closed exception or I get an unable to get browser exception. What happened? I check through all the IE settings and versions and nothing is springing out at me as to the cause of the problem. Let me show some hard code...

```
var ieops = new InternetExplorerOptions(){
      IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
      EnsureCleanSession = true,
      RequireWindowFocus = true
   };
wrapperObject = (new InternetExplorerDriver(ieops));
wrapperObject.webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url1);
Console.WriteLine("This will give an exception {0}",wrapperObject.webDriver.Title);
```

The answer must be simple and staring me in the face, but I have no idea in which direction to stare back.

Comment: Your tests sound unstable, just like you asked them to be. You're setting the `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` option. I strongly suspect that is you remove that option, and set the Protected Mode settings to be properly configured for use with the IE driver, it will work better for you.

Comment: No. Removing that option doesn't change the behavior. Probably it shouldn't be there in the first place as I do have that ProtectedMode box checked in all 4 zones already. Frankly I suspect it was a weekend software update that has derailed my testing, but I'll be ... if I can see any trace of said update.

Comment: Just to add. I re-installed IE11 to verify that nothing was broken in my browser config. That involved a clean boot and a lot of patching. Exactly the same behaviour ensued. Is there any expert who can offer a starting point for investigation around this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found an answer of sorts; in that the test execution now occurs

```
var ieops = new InternetExplorerOptions(){
      InnitialBrowserUrl = TheUrlIUse,
      EnsureCleanSession = true,
      RequireWindowFocus = true
   };
```

The above fixes the issue on the particular boxes in question. I am at a loss to understand why the code should execute differently on 2 different boxes. That's not the kind of repeatability I like in testing. What's going on in that initial navigation? Answers on a postcard please.